# Getting dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting- UBUNTU

Tags: 16.04, 16.10

I am new to Ubuntu and I am getting this error while doing an upgrade or installing a package

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'libpolkit-gobject-1-0:amd64' is missing final newline
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

I am using the latest ubuntu version 16. I wanted to make my desktop look like windows so I tried this http://www.pcworld.com/article/2028896/how-to-make-ubuntu-linux-look-like-windows-7.html. i dont know exactly if this can be the issue.

Forgot to mention that I have already tried several tricks but none are working.

Answer (score 0):

Probably dpkg list file archive is corrupted.

1. clear file `/var/lib/dpkg/info/libpolkit-gobject-1-0\:amd64.info`
2. reinstall package `sudo apt-get install libpolkit-gobject-1-0 --reinstall`

Comment: Thanks for the help but Nothing worked for me. At last I reinstalled Ubuntu with all default settings and it worked.

Comment: The *.info file contain only list files of package. I've same problem and replacing empty file as info file I've resolve the problem.